# angularjs 1.x filter for array type

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have lot of objects like below in array now i want to apply filter on it. How i can apply filter like i have mention in image:

[image]

Can i use simple AngularJS filter on it?

Kindly help me with best approach to apply these filter. Thanks in advance. I have multiple hotels data like that in this JSON. But I am not butting it all because of space.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
        "name": "subways",
        "city": "lahore",
        "area": "johar town",
        "min_order": "200 AED",
        "del_time": "1 hour",
        "del_fees": "1 AED",
        "pre_order": "NA",
        "rating_star": "4",
        "rating_no": 514,
        "status": "OPEN",
        "__v": 0,
        "categories": [
            {
                "_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
                "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
                "name": "subways Burger",
                "category_id": "1",
                "__v": 0,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "_id": "57da7973d0b5e2059c5ff10a",
                        "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
                        "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
                        "logo": "abcLogo",
                        "name": "subway item 1",
                        "detail": "great item",
                        "price": "10",
                        "rating": "5",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "57da79e8d0b5e2059c5ff10b",
                        "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
                        "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
                        "logo": "abcLogo",
                        "name": "subway item 2",
                        "detail": "great item",
                        "price": "10",
                        "rating": "5",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "57da79efd0b5e2059c5ff10c",
                        "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
                        "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
                        "logo": "abcLogo",
                        "name": "subway item 3",
                        "detail": "great item",
                        "price": "10",
                        "rating": "5",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "57da79fcd0b5e2059c5ff10d",
                        "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
                        "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
                        "logo": "abcLogo",
                        "name": "subway item 4",
                        "detail": "great item",
                        "price": "10",
                        "rating": "5",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
]
```

Comment: if it's an angular2 app, you would need to implement a custom pipe/filter and use it, because angular2 doesn't have built-in sort filter due to performance issue.

Comment: Of course you can use Angular JS filters on it, so could you go ahead and show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: no im not doing it in angular2 it's in angular 1.x

Comment: Did you try reading the filter documentation? This question is too broad and shows no research effort. Update the question with your specific problem

Comment: sufian saory please give me your skype plz

Answer (score 0):

A simple AngularJS filter to handle such operations is shown below:

```js
angular.module("myapp", [])
  .controller("myctrl", function myctrl($scope) {

    $scope.cityIncludes = [];
     
  
    $scope.includeCity = function(city) {
       console.log( city );
      var i = $scope.cityIncludes.indexOf(city);
      if (i > -1) {
        $scope.cityIncludes.splice(i, 1);
      } else {
        $scope.cityIncludes.push(city);
      }
      console.log( $scope.cityIncludes);
    }

    $scope.cityFilter = function(city) {
      if ($scope.cityIncludes.length > 0) {
        if ($scope.cityIncludes.indexOf(city.city) < 0)
          return;
      }

      return city;
    }

    $scope.rests = [{
      "_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
      "name": "Lahore Restaurant",
      "city": "lahore",
      "area": "johar town",
      "min_order": "200 AED",
      "del_time": "1 hour",
      "del_fees": "1 AED",
      "pre_order": "NA",
      "rating_star": "4",
      "rating_no": 514,
      "status": "OPEN",
      "__v": 0,
      "categories": [{
        "_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
        "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
        "name": "subways Burger",
        "category_id": "1",
        "__v": 0,
        "items": [{
          "_id": "57da7973d0b5e2059c5ff10a",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 1",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79e8d0b5e2059c5ff10b",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 2",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79efd0b5e2059c5ff10c",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 3",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79fcd0b5e2059c5ff10d",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 4",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
      "name": "islamabad rest",
      "city": "islamabad",
      "area": "johar town",
      "min_order": "200 AED",
      "del_time": "1 hour",
      "del_fees": "1 AED",
      "pre_order": "NA",
      "rating_star": "4",
      "rating_no": 514,
      "status": "OPEN",
      "__v": 0,
      "categories": [{
        "_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
        "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
        "name": "subways Burger",
        "category_id": "1",
        "__v": 0,
        "items": [{
          "_id": "57da7973d0b5e2059c5ff10a",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 1",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79e8d0b5e2059c5ff10b",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 2",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79efd0b5e2059c5ff10c",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 3",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79fcd0b5e2059c5ff10d",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 4",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
      "name": "abcd",
      "city": "rawalpindi",
      "area": "johar town",
      "min_order": "200 AED",
      "del_time": "1 hour",
      "del_fees": "1 AED",
      "pre_order": "NA",
      "rating_star": "4",
      "rating_no": 514,
      "status": "OPEN",
      "__v": 0,
      "categories": [{
        "_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
        "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
        "name": "subways Burger",
        "category_id": "1",
        "__v": 0,
        "items": [{
          "_id": "57da7973d0b5e2059c5ff10a",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 1",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79e8d0b5e2059c5ff10b",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 2",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79efd0b5e2059c5ff10c",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 3",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79fcd0b5e2059c5ff10d",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 4",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
      "name": "asdadsasdasdas",
      "city": "karachi",
      "area": "johar town",
      "min_order": "200 AED",
      "del_time": "1 hour",
      "del_fees": "1 AED",
      "pre_order": "NA",
      "rating_star": "4",
      "rating_no": 514,
      "status": "OPEN",
      "__v": 0,
      "categories": [{
        "_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
        "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
        "name": "subways Burger",
        "category_id": "1",
        "__v": 0,
        "items": [{
          "_id": "57da7973d0b5e2059c5ff10a",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 1",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79e8d0b5e2059c5ff10b",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 2",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79efd0b5e2059c5ff10c",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 3",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79fcd0b5e2059c5ff10d",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 4",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      "_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
      "name": "multan asdasda",
      "city": "multan",
      "area": "johar town",
      "min_order": "200 AED",
      "del_time": "1 hour",
      "del_fees": "1 AED",
      "pre_order": "NA",
      "rating_star": "4",
      "rating_no": 514,
      "status": "OPEN",
      "__v": 0,
      "categories": [{
        "_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
        "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
        "name": "subways Burger",
        "category_id": "1",
        "__v": 0,
        "items": [{
          "_id": "57da7973d0b5e2059c5ff10a",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 1",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79e8d0b5e2059c5ff10b",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 2",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79efd0b5e2059c5ff10c",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 3",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }, {
          "_id": "57da79fcd0b5e2059c5ff10d",
          "restaurant_id": "57da6aeb4eafac04afd01bc5",
          "category_id": "57da72e94eafac04afd01bc9",
          "logo": "abcLogo",
          "name": "subway item 4",
          "detail": "great item",
          "price": "10",
          "rating": "5",
          "__v": 0
        }]
      }]
    }]
  });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">


  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="rest in rests  track by rest.city">
      <input name="rest.city" type="checkbox" value="rest.city" ng-click="includeCity(rest.city)">
      <label for="rest.city">{{rest.city}}</label>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="rest in rests | filter: cityFilter">
      <p ng-bind="rest.name"></p>
      <p ng-bind="'Rating ' + rest.rating_star"></p>
      <p ng-bind="'Status ' + rest.status"></p>
      <p ng-bind="'Area ' + rest.area"></p>
    </li>
  </ul>


</body>
```

You can use this concept.

Comment: can you please tell me how i can perform this same action on click "open restaurant" radio button. mean i want when some one click on open restaurants then all hotels will check status='open' and show

Comment: It's quite simple - you can create filters out of each key in the response. I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: thanks nikjohn for help can you please tell update it on these three steps

1.input type on search name
2.select box on select open restaurant on behalf of "OPEN"
3.Check box on Cuisines select. 
plz perform these three thanks

Comment: I've added a sample filter. You can extend this to any extend you want. You can filter by city, open status and whatever else you want. Let me know if you have any queries. Greetings from across the border brother

Comment: thank you nikjohn for helping. Greeting from across the border thanks bro. haha

Comment: If my answer helped, please upvote and mark as correct

Comment: nikjohn please help me also this i have cuisines:['indian','arbian','amarican'] in every hotel how i will find by cuisine mean show only hotel that have cuisines 'indian' etc. as mention in above image. thanks for your time bro

Comment: Where do you get the cuisines from? I don't see it in the list

Comment: http://eiconixdev.com/angular/search.html
check out the  link bro here i want to sort the cuisines.

Comment: You could either convert the `cuisines` object into an array like:

`"cuisines":"['india','pakistan','arabic']"` and then filter it in the same way as above, or split the string `"india,pakistan,arabic"` using `String.prototype.split` and then filter it

Comment: bro thank for filter now i have to apply sorting on these filter data how i can do plz help me also in this 
i have these filters
rating,newest,a to z , min order amount , fast deliver

Answer (score 0):

i have done

i have radio box for all type of cuisines when any one select. i save it into scope type variable with below function. now question is how i filter it bro.

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input name="rest.cusine" type="radio" value="india" ng-click="filterCuisine('indian')">
      <label for="open status">india</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input name="rest.cusine" type="radio" value="india" ng-click="filterCuisine('pakistani')">
      <label for="open status">pakistan</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input name="rest.cusine" type="radio" value="arabic" ng-click="filterCuisine('arabic')">
      <label for="open status">arabic</label>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Function for getting the selected cuisine

```
$scope.filterCuisine = function(cuisine){
  $scope.checkFilterCuisine = cuisine;
  console.log($scope.checkFilterCuisine);
}
```

how i apply filter on this function

```
$scope.selectCuisine = function(city){
  console.log(city.cuisines);
 if (city.cuisines.length > 0 && $scope.checkFilterCuisine != '') {
   if (city.cuisines.indexOf($scope.checkFilterCuisine) < 0){
        return;
      }
  }
   return city;
}
```